# BroadcastReceiver not receiving boolean value after AlarmManager finishes set time

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I am using a BroadcastReceiver to enable a button when it is triggered. I have an AlarmManager that runs for a certain amount of time. When the time has elapsed, it sends a broadcast like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent("polarCap1Status");
i.putExtra("polarCap1Stat", true);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);
```

I use this code to receive the broadcast:

```
//broadcast receiver to allow button to be clicked again
mMessageReceiver1 = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        clickOnOff1 = intent.getBooleanExtra("polarCap1Stat", false);
        polarCap1.setEnabled(clickOnOff1);
        updateScores();
        resources.edit().putBoolean("pc1Set", false).commit();
    }//end onReceive function
};
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver1, new IntentFilter("polarCap1Status"));
```

I have the receiver setup in my manifest like so:

```
<receiver android:name="com.twentytwentythree.sab.SetupTimerPC1" >
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name="polarCap1Status" /> 
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

SetupTimerPC1 is the name of the class that is sending the broadcast. It is sending it to another class called runGraphics.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Edit:

I added an intent-filter to the receiver in the manifest but it has not changed anything.

Comment: `<receiver android:name="com.twentytwentythree.sab.SetupTimerPC1" />` add a intent filter to your manifest to be able to receive the broadcast message you broadcast like this: `<intent-filter> <action android:name="polarCap1Status" /> </intent-filter>`

Comment: Please make sure your sending broadcast and registering receiver code is called, you can verify this by printing some log.

Comment: @bean_droid After adding the intent-filter, there is no change.

Comment: @Leog The broadcast is only sent when I keep the app up and going. If I close it, it no longer sends the broadcast. I assumed it would work find when I am using an AlarmManager.